# Remove and store an array item without creating garbage

Tags: javascript, arrays, garbage-collection, pool

I'm looking for a performant way to remove and store elements from an array. I am trying to make an object pool to reduce garbage collections calls.

Just as `.pop()` and `.unshift()` remove elements from an array and return the value of that element, I'd like to be able to remove an element at a specific index, while storing it's value in a variable, and while not creating unnecessary arrays/objects.

`.splice()` removes the element at a specific index just fine, and stores that value in an array. I can access that, but the function itself creates a new array, which will eventually trigger the garbage collector.

`.slice()` has the same issue, a new array is created.

Is there a way to pull out and store a specific indexed element without the creation of a new array?

Comment: If you don't want to amend the source array, use `var item = array[index]; delete array[index];`. You'll manually get rid of the element in the array setting its value to `undefined`.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't remove item from array, but rather changes that item to be undefined. see array length after delete

Comment: @ VisioN if a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] then on scratchpad in Firefox delete a[4] gives a=[0,1,2,3,,5,6,7,8,9] whereas I presume OP wants [0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: If the OP wants `[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]` then there is not other way than using `s(p)lice`.

Comment: @ VisioN When a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] is it true that using var item = a[4]; a.splice(4,1); will create a new array? I thought it just altered the existing array. In scratchpad I get item=4 and a=[0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: @jing3142 What he means is that `Array.prototype.splice` will return a new array (of the removed elements). Which will trigger the GC later. OP's looking for a way to avoid that

Comment: Why not implement a splice that doesn't create a new array?

Comment: @Esailija That might avoid triggering the GC, but it might also end up being slower in itself because it won't be optimized, right?

Comment: @SomeGuy it will not only be optimized but it will be much faster than any built-in function because you can avoid semantic complexity like holed arrays.

Comment: @Esailija Can you provide an example of a splice implementation that doesn't create a new array?

Comment: @jackrugile look at https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/array.js#762 , what do you need from splice? It does many things :) Do you just need to move _one_ element? How close is their position to the end (with a large enough pool size N, the O(1) of a linked list might be better than the O(N) of deleting from an array).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum linked lists perform so shit in javascript that you better have a huge list and lots of deletions in the middle before even considering it over a tight array :P related http://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/

Comment: @Esailija which is why I said "with a large enough pool". Linked Lists perform poorly in any language, not just JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This always removes one item at `index`, if you need to remove more than 1 consecutive items at a time, it would be
more efficient to implement it to take a `howMany` argument and remove them in a batch instead of calling
`removeAt` repeatedly.

```
function removeAt(array, index) {
    // Assumes array and index are always valid values
    // place validation code here if needed
    var len = array.length;
    // for example if index is not valid here, it will deoptimize the function
    var ret = array[index];
    for (var i = index + 1; i < len; ++i) {
        array[i - 1] = array[i];
    }
    array.length = len - 1;
    return ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5]
var removed = removeAt(a, 2);
console.log(a);
// [1, 2, 4, 5]
console.log(removed);
// 3
```

Comment: If Jack doesn't care about the order of the arrays, the function might be faster this way: `arr[index] = arr[0]; return arr.shift();`

Comment: @SomeGuy that doesn't make any sense, shift needs to move all elements in the array

Comment: True. I guess I'm just giving native function optimizations too much credit

Comment: @SomeGuy yes you are, for example I have implemented a double-ended queue that is 4x faster than `.shift` even when the V8 trick is applied, and 10000000000x faster than `.shift` when the array is too large to apply the V8 trick. https://github.com/petkaantonov/deque#why-not-use-an-array

Comment: Why are you caching the length for the loop?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum why not?

Comment: It's an extra variable and as far as I know it doesn't help with performance (or readability) at all. So I was wondering why you added it

Comment: cos the hoisting optimization is extremely unreliable

Comment: `i < array.length` reads the length from memory for every iteration of the loop, where as `i < len` stores the length in register for the entire loop. However the optimization that would make these equal is extremely unreliable so might as well write `i < len` every time

Comment: Thanks Esailija, a friend recommended a similar method and I am doing some testing with it now. Looks promising! Much appreciated.

I'm always looking to increase performance for my HTML5 games. Would you recommend deque for any game uses?

Comment: Thankyou Esailija, this will save me a LOT of headaches! For those interested I have created a jsperf test for a simplified version of the removeAt function that doesn't return the removed item, and it is significantly faster than array.splice. https://jsperf.com/array-splice-vs-custom-garbage-free-alternative/1